# start-transcript causes script to fail in a background job

Tags: powershell

I am creating a powershell script as a background job using start-job which then logs it's output using start-transcript. Below is the code of both:

**a**

```
start-job  -filepath ./b.ps1 -ArgumentList 'test.txt'
wait-job *
```

**b**

```
param([parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$logfile)
Set-PSDebug -Strict
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
start-transcript $logfile
```

**output of ./a.ps1**

```
Id              Name            State      HasMoreData     Location             Command                  
--              ----            -----      -----------     --------             -------                  
1               Job1            Running    True            localhost            param...                 
1               Job1            Failed     False           localhost            param...                 
2               Job2            Failed     False           localhost            param...
```

**Output of ./b.ps1 -log c:\test.txt**

```
Transcript started, output file is test.txt
Transcript stopped, output file is C:\test.txt
```

I have also done some testing by setting "echo here" lines to confirm that is the line playing up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently Start-Transcript isn't supported in background jobs.  If you do a Receive-Job to look at the script output you're likely to see an error like this:

```
This host does not support transcription.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotImplemented: (:) [Start-Transcript], PSNotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NotSupported,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartTranscriptCommand
```

BTW in PowerShell 2.0 I recommend you switch from `Set-PSDebug -strict` to `Set-StrictMode -Version 2.0` - it will catch more potential errors.

Comment: Ah that explains it, thank you for that information and the tip about debug strict.