# Start-transcript in a background process

Tags: powershell, background-process

is there a way to handle start-transcript in a background process? I have a script launched in background. almost everything works fine, except logging with start-transcript? in fact, it creates my $filelog.txt but doesn't write anything in it?

Comment: Might be related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835997/start-transcript-causes-script-to-fail-in-a-background-job

Comment: I don't see something really useful there.

Comment: Look better. And show your script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [start-transcript causes script to fail in a background job](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835997/start-transcript-causes-script-to-fail-in-a-background-job)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it, non-interactive PowerShell hosts (in your case background job) don't support host output Cmdlets like Start-Transcript, Write-Host etc. You'd have to use you own logging functions or output messages to file via Out-File for example.