# How can I create a log of a powershell script running in the background?

Tags: powershell, command

I have a powershell script that I am converting from running as a fore-front infinite while-loop to a scheduled task. The biggest problem here is that I would still like to maintain a log. Start-Transcript was the bit that did the logging previously, but that doesn't work with the background task.

These links ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835997/start-transcript-causes-script-to-fail-in-a-background-job), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710613/start-transcript-in-a-background-process)) show similar questions, but they only give the information that start-transcript won't work. They don't give any indication as to how it *could* be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can do two things:

- Add logging routines to your script (see for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38527767/1630171)).
- Run the script like this:

  ```
  powershell.exe -Command "&{your.ps1 *> your.log; exit $LASTEXITCODE}"
  ```

Personally I'd prefer the former, but it'd require more changes to your code.

Comment: Thanks! I've been working on it for the last bit, and I've found a pretty good solution. I was hoping for something more automatic like Start-Transcript, but so it goes.      I ended up using this guy's library, though a little modified. http://9to5it.com/powershell-logging-function-library/